# Android Emulator white screen (E/SurfaceFlinger: GL error 0x0502)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, boot

I'm running Android Studio 2.3.2 on my Windows 10 desktop. Before today, whenever I pressed the run app button it would launch the emulator with no problems (except the occasional white screen, but closing and relaunching would fix this).

However, today no matter how many times I restart the emulator it gives me an unusable white screen the instant I turn it on. The phone emulator doesn't even get to the android boot screen and android studio never gets past the "Waiting for target device to come online phase", so it's not my app. I looked everywhere and cannot find a solution to my problem, but I have so far:

- Disabled 'Instant Run'
- Deleted both my emulators and reinstalled the one
- Turned android studio off and on again

The error code I keep getting in the android monitor is:

E/SurfaceFlinger: GL error 0x0502

Here is a hopefully helpful image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xsk0W.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by disabling Multi-Core CPU (Experimental) setting
1) Goes to Android Virtual Device Manager
2) Open your Android Virtual Device configuration
3) Show Advanced Settings
4) Uncheck Multi-Core CPU setting